# Bash subprocess is getting duplicated

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm facing a behavior where a code that is running in a background bash subprocess (between parentesis and &) is being sometimes, apparently, called twice:

That's the case:

```
# script start.sh
#!/bin/bash

echo "Starting ..."

(
  java -server ...

  ret=$?
  log "Process has stopped returning: [$ret]"
  exit $ret
) &
```

In a normal scenario, running the start.sh script, two process would be created, one for the start.sh itself and other for the background bash subprocess (java program):

```
#> ps -ef | grep ^user
user 24538     1  0 Oct22 ?        00:00:00 /bin/bash start.sh
user 24539 24538  2 Oct22 ?        06:20:56 java -server ...
```

But, after a few days a new java process, that is child of 24539 process (java), is being created:

```
#> ps -ef | grep ^user
user 24538     1  0 Oct22 ?        00:00:00 /bin/bash start.sh
user 24539 24538 18 Oct22 ?        06:20:56 java -server ...
user 25888 24539  2 Oct25 ?        00:00:00 java -server ...
```

Does anyone have any idea why/how it's happening?

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with the shell; if `bash` were involved, the parent process id of the new Java process would be 24538, not 24539. The Java process is forking itself. You'd have to look at the code to see why.

Comment: Yes Chepner, that's was my first thought, but this Java code doesn't do anything capable to fork itself. It only run an OSGI lib code (without any thread), that blocks until start.sh is killed or OSGI receive a "exit" command and then java process finishs "elegantly", and the background bash subprocess too.

Comment: You might try running the Java process with `strace` to see where it is calling `fork`.

Comment: I can't run strace now cause the process is frozen and, even if I restart it, we never know when it's gonna happen. But thanks anyway for the suggestion.